# python read all files in a folder except a file named "xyz"

Tags: python

I want to read all files in a folder except a file named "xyz". When I reach to this file, I want to skip it and read the next one.

Currently I have the following code:

```
for file in glob.glob('*.xml'):
    data = open(file).read()
    print(file)
```

Obviously, this will read all files in that folder. How should I skip the file "xyz.xml"

Comment: there are bunch of simple ways to make it through. you should think about it yourself first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `continue` keyword is useful for skipping an iteration of a for loop:

```
for file in glob.glob('*.xml'):
    if file=="xyz.xml":
        continue
    data = open(file).read()
    print(file)
```

Comment: As per suggestion of @SylvainLeroux (a comment in my answer), you can use `glob.iglob` to use an iterator, if that is a concern. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in [f for f in glob.glob('*.xml') if f != "xyz.xml"]:
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: Use a generator expression, so you don't create the whole array.

Comment: @utdemir Might even use [iglob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) so it will never store the entire list into memory.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, assuming that the element to be removed is in the list returned by `glob.glob()` (if that's not guaranteed, put the `remove()` line inside a `try` block):

```
lst = glob.glob('*.xml')
lst.remove('xyz.xml') # assuming that the element is present in the list
for file in lst:
    pass
```

Or if you care about memory usage, use a generator:

```
for file in (file for file in glob.glob('*.xml') if file != 'xyz.xml'):
    pass
```

Comment: Might be because this throws an error if `xyz.xml` isn't in the list? I'm not the downvoter, though.

Comment: Downvoter here. Allocating the list and removing an element afterwards is pretty unnecessary(Probably glob returns a list, but one shouldn't rely on it). You're allocating O(n) memory, and you're traversing the list to search for "xyz.xml", which passes over the list, and calling remove which moves data on memory, which has also linear complexity.

The whole thing can be simply done on constant memory and one pass over resulting list.

Comment: @utdemir read the documentation of `glob.glob()` : "Return a possibly-empty list of path names". The list was _already_ allocated, that function returns a list. It's evean cheaper to remove the element in the first place (as I did above) than to create a new list comprehension or generator expression

Comment: @ÓscarLópez, list.remove has the possibility to reallocating the whole array, probably it won't, but why should we rely on that, since we can easily skip the element via generators/continue statement? I think one should always aim for worst-case complexity.

Answer (score 2):

For sake of completeness as no one posted the most obvious version:

```
for file in glob.glob('*.xml'):
    if file != 'xyz.xml':
        data = open(file).read()
        print(file)
```

Comment: I like this option too, but in python it unfortunately requires an extra level of indendation for the whole block.

Comment: @AndrewJohnson Yes. But I don't know if the OP cares about that, though ;)

Comment: wondering the difference between this option and Andrew's answer. Any advantages on running time or memory allocation?

Comment: @ahri According to [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html), Andrew's answer takes 3 extra bytes once compiled (an extra `JUMP_FORWARD` opcode). But honestly, this is sooooo marginal...

Answer (score 1):

You can use glob for fairly simple pattern matching but remember that pattern rules for glob are not regular expressions!
Below code can help you exclude all xml files that start with 'X'

```
files = glob.glob('[!X]*.xml')
```